# How can I trace a global variable in Perl?

Tags: perl, file, io

I'm looking at someone elses code, and they open a file as such:

```
(open (FILEHANDLE,'/homedirectory/textfile.txt'))
```

they then put the contents of each line into a variable for processing (each line of the file consists of data separated by tabs):

```
while(<FILEHANDLE>) {
($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4) = split (/\t+/, $_);
```

then he does something like:

```
$index = join('_', $var1, $var2, $var3);
```

and then does THIS (the part where I scratch my head)

```
$contents = $filehandle{"$index"};
```

I tried printing out `$contents`, and it looked like it was the values of `$var1`, `$var2` and `$var3` all separated by a semicolon (e.g. "`value1;value2;value3`").  In addition, I changed the name of `FILEHANDLE` to `FILEHANDLE2` and did the same for `$filehandle` and i got the exact same result, so this leads me to believe that they are related.  Also, when leaving `FILEHANDLE` alone and changing `$filehandle` to `$filehandle2`, nothing shows up.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I've been stuck on this for quite a while.  Also, I'm a perl n00b...(I mostly program in Python).

By request, here is a more complete version of the code:

```
sub myfn{
    $filename = "home/textfile.txt";
    open(FILEHANDLE, $filename) || die "Can't find filename\n";
    while (<FILEHANDLE>) {
        ($var1, $var2, $var3) = split (/\t+/, $_);
        $used_index = join ('_', $var1, $var2, $var3);  
        $tmp_index = uc ($used_index)
        $contents = $filehandle{"$tmp_index"};
```

to be clear, `$filehandle` appears for the first time at this juncture... it also may be  of note that something with a similar name is set earlier, but it's like this:

```
abcd_filehandle{"$randomvar} = "VALUEX;VALUEY;VALUEZ";
```

Comment: Any chance you could post the complete code snippet?

Comment: This doesn't look like a correct syntax in the first place. Could you please copy/paste the code instead of typing it? (e.g. are you sure it's `$filehandle(` and not `$filehandle{` or `$filehandle[`?

Comment: ah, yes sorry about that. let me fix it

Comment: %filehandle hash MUST be set somewhere - possibly outside myfn. Can you please do `grep filehandle` on the entire code? Also, `abcd_filehandle("$randomvar)` looks like a similary broken syntax - you can't use function call as lvalue AFAIR

Comment: Can you do the following as the FIRST line of `sub myfn`: `use Data::Dumper; print Data::Dumper->Dump([\%filehandle]);` and post the result?

Comment: I did...with a grep -i I get all reference to FILEHANDLE and $filehandle, but the first reference I see to $filehandle is the line i showed you above...

these lines are at the very tope of the file...not sure if it would help :

    `use Common_Extract;

    use Time::localtime;

    use sort '_mergesort';`

Comment: I don't see anything when I add those lines...:( Thanks for your help, though! I'll post the results of what happened when I figure it out.

Comment: Please do grep without -i and post 100% of results if feasible. The line being first is not necessarily relevant since what matters is the lines prior to the call(s) to subroutine `myfn()` - which can come AFTER the sub's code

Comment: @user - what do you mean you don't see anything? Data::Dumper ALWAYS prints something, at the very least `$VAR1 = {}` `$VAR1 = undef` or something like that even if the data's missing

Comment: This seems to be an excellent time to ponder why global variables are almost always a bad idea and why `use strict` is your friend.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: As Mr. Karonen alluded to, the identifier `filehandle` (in your case, considering the usage `$filehandle{$key}`, the identifier is a hash `%filehandle`) has NOTHING to do with the bareword `FILEHANDLE`. They just happen to be named similarly (but not at all identically as Perl is case sensitive).

Most likely, the hash `%filehandle` - named very poorly by the way since its values don't seem to actually be filehandles - is populated elsewhere in the code. To verify that, you need to do 2 things:

- run a `grep` command on your file as follows: `grep filehandle your_file.pl`
- Check what the content of that hash is when the subroutine is called, by starting your method with:

  ```
  sub myfn{
      use Data::Dumper; 
      print Data::Dumper->Dump([\%filehandle]);
  ```
- See where that variable is changed in the code by running your script through a Perl debugger (take your current command line and pre-pend it with `perl -d`). When in the debugger, set a watch expression by issuing command `w %filehandle` and then execute the script via `c` (continue)

Looking at the code posted, it seems to have been written in very poor form using global variables. The problem you are having with understanding it is a 100% perfect example of just why using global variables in any language is a Very Bad Idea. Contrast this with the code that I would have written for this purpose (provided my guesses are correct about what %filehandle is):

```
# Caller code
my %file_data = (1=>2); # What the original code called %filehandle hash
myfn(\%file_data); # Pass by reference

sub myfn {
    my($file_data) = @_; # A hashref, passed from caller code
    my $filename = "home/textfile.txt";
    open(my $filehandle, "<", $filename) || die "Can't find filename. Error: $!\n";
    while (<$filehandle>) {
        my ($var1, $var2, $var3) = split (/\t+/, $_);
        my $used_index = join ('_', $var1, $var2, $var3);  
        my $uc_index = uc($used_index);
        my $contents = $file_data->{$uc_index}; # Using -> to dereference hashref
```

Comment: Thanks i'll use the perl debugger! Like I said I'm new to perl, so :(

Comment: Also, in the debugger you can do `b myfn` to set breakpoint on myfn; do `c` to go to that breakpoint, then examine contents of %filehandle via `x %filehandle`

Comment: Even if they had the same case, `FILEHANDLE` (short for `*FILEHANDLE`) is not the same variable as `%FILEHANDLE`.

Comment: Actually, I smell something worse than just global variables. Even if my instinct is wrong, the OP would do (him|her)self a service by reading: http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html and http://perl.plover.com/varvarname2.html and http://perl.plover.com/varvarname3.html

Answer (score 0):

See [perldoc perlopentut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html).  Both

```
open FILEHANDLE, '<', 'filename' or die $!;
while (<FILEHANDLE>) {
    # do something with $_
}
close FILEHANDLE;
```

and

```
open $filehandle, '<', 'filename' or die $!;
while (<$filehandle>) {
    # do something with $_
}
close $filehandle;
```

are valid ways to open and read a file, but the bareword `FILEHANDLE` and the scalar variable `$filehandle` have nothing to do with each other (unless you've previously set `$filehandle =  \*FILEHANDLE` or something like that).  You can even do

```
open my $filehandle, '<', 'filename' or die $!;
while (<$filehandle>) {
    # do something with $_
}
# file is closed automatically when $filehandle goes out of scope
```

and, indeed, some would consider this the recommended way to open files in modern Perl.

Comment: the thing is it seems like $filehandle is some sort of hash...It didn't make sense to me either and this person didn't comment their code at all so it's terrible to read through :(

Comment: @user1030592: `$filehandle{$index}` refers to the entry indexed by `$index` in the hash `%filehandle`.  It has nothing to do with the scalar variable `$filehandle` (except for living in the same symbol table entry, if it's a package variable).  I agree that it can be confusing (and so does Larry Wall, apparently); see [perldoc perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) for details.